# I am having issues using jQuery to show and hide a dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've tried looking at multiple different sources and different codes. None of them have worked for me, and I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I apologize if it looks like an amateur, as I'm young and quickly copied code from my website onto jsfiddle. I would really appreciate any help, because I have been stuck on this for days and have lost my mind over it, when it is probably something simple.

[Link to my code](http://jsfiddle.net/j6n1wgad/8/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="nav_container">
  <div class="nav_header">
  </div>
  <div class="nav_content">
    <ul class="nav_list">
      <li>
    <a href="/">
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
      </li>
      <li id="categories_list">
    <a href="#">
          <span>Categories</span>
    </a>
      </li>
      <li id="me_list">
    <a href="#">
      <span>Me</span>
    </a>
      </li>
      <li>
    <a href="/categories/all">
      <span>Games A-Z</span>
    </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="/">
  <img src="/thumbs/header_image_white.png" style="position:relative; height: 103px;">
  </a>
</div>
    <div id="categories_dropdown_menu">
      <ul class="dropdown_menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Action</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Action-Adventure</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Adventure</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Arcade</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Multiplayer</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Racing</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    </br>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Role-Playing</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Shooting</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Simulation</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Sports</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>Strategy</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        <span>All</span>
      </a>
    </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#categories_list").click(function(){
    $("#categories_dropdown_menu").slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
</script>
```

I want the dropdown menu to be the width of the whole page, and that is why the ul is not within the categories_list id.

EDIT: My bad, I forgot to include the dropdown menu, although I thought I had. I updated link and HTML. If you could look over it, now, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You have some issues with your markup in your example, first of all you don't have any `#categories_dropdown_menu` try to revisit and change your markup.

Comment: In your example jsfiddle, you've not included jQuery and also included <script> tag in jsFiddle which is not required. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/98ws25y3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included jQuery in your jsFiddle.

And also in the JS section, you don't need to include the script tag.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/98ws25y3/)**

Instead of above approach for showing the drop down menu, I would prefer pure CSS approach for showing the drop down menu:

```css
ul.nav_list li ul {
 display: none;
}
ul.nav_list li:hover ul {
   display: block;
  /* make position absolute and give width to be 100% to make it take full width*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav_list">
<li> <a href="/">
  <span>Home</span>
</a>

</li>
<li id="categories_list"> <a href="#">
      <span>Categories</span>
</a>

    <ul class="dropdown_menu">
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Action</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Action-Adventure</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Adventure</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Arcade</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Multiplayer</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Racing</span>
  </a>

        </li>
       
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Role-Playing</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Shooting</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Simulation</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Sports</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>Strategy</span>
  </a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="/">
<span>All</span>
  </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="me_list"> <a href="#">
  <span>Me</span>
</a>

</li>
<li> <a href="/categories/all">
  <span>Games A-Z</span>
</a>

</li>
</ul>
```

In your page, you need to make few CSS changes:

```
ul.nav_list li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  background: gray;
}

.nav_content {
 // remove overflow: hidden;
}
```

image:

[image]

Comment: Mohamedrias, your code works perfectly, and I understand it. I tried adding the code to my website, which is [here](https://www.sta-games.com/index_test.php), and it does not work. When you hover over categories, it does not work properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated answer. You have set overflow hidden for nav menu and also the css for second level drop down menu is not proper

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it to work. The only problem is, it is still not going the full width of the page when I add "width: 100%," but I will figure it out. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Great, you're welcome. Else go with previous approach using JS and use mouseover event instead of click, it will work as well :) Please accept the answer if it has solved the issue